# Integrate a chat system in my website

Tags: php, facebook, xmpp, chat

I want to integrate the Facebook chat system in my PHP based website. I have 
searched [developers.facebok.com](http://developers.facebok.com) for data, but it says very little about [Jabber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol), and I don't know how to use it. If you could post some step-by-step tutorial for integration of Facebook chat or any link for that tutorial that would be so nice of you.

I just want to add Facebook chat as I need to do add some on action events for this chat.
So I want a code tutorial for this. I'm searching for any direct code embedding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think that you can embed existing Facebook chat so you have to write your own client. As Facebook chat protocol is Jabber/XMPP, you have to implement a chat with XMPP capability.

There are some libraries mentioned on `http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/`. Maybe there is also a ready-to-use XMPP chat software.

Answer (score 1):

Give [Jaxl](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/) PHP Library a try which also supports [X-FACEBOOK-PLATFORM](http://abhinavsingh.com/blog/2012/09/how-to-perform-x-facebook-platform-and-google-talk-x-oauth2-xmpp-authentication-with-php-jaxl-library/) authentication method. There are plenty of examples [xfacebook_platform_client.php](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL/blob/v3.x/examples/xfacebook_platform_client.php) to help getting started.

Answer (score 0):

Direct code embedding of facebook related chat , you can consider impossible since integrating  facebook chat is really a tough job and people actually pay and get it , for example CometChat . The second point is that , since your website is purely php based , it will be much more difficult . Better use nodejs to create a socket server make a chat in Javascript that would connect to our **Nodejs** server.

As you , go through this implementation , your job will no longer seem hard . Believe me , it took me months to realise that php wrecks in this area of chat .